# Always show filter cell editors in RadGridView - Telerik for WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, telerik

I am using a basic `RadGridView` to show some data in a WinForms application.  I have set the `RadGridView` to `EnableFiltering` and that is working just peachy.  I have also set the `GridFilterCellElement` to `Collapse` both the filter icon, and the filter cell text that says "Contains:", and "Equals:", etc. The filter cells essentially look like empty grey cells right now, until one of them gets focus... at which point in time the proper editor fills the cell.  I am setting the visibility of the filter icon and the filter cell text in the `ViewCellFormatting` handler of the `RadGridView`.

What I want to know, is how can I just make the editors for the entire row of filter cells, just show by default?  In other words, I just want to show the editors in the filter cells at all times so it is completely obvious that the user can filter the data with the editing controls above.

I thought this was going to be very easy, but it has proven to be quite tricky.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against showing the editors at all times, despite the fact it will not be a trivial task, there is a reason for the editors to work the way they do.

Editors basically consist of some controls in them - being text box, drop down list, date picker etc. Controls, as we know are not lightweight objects (having plenty of controls shown will have significant performance impact) and do have some limitations e.g. they don't support clipping.

As RadGridView uses virtualization for its cells, cell elements are being reused during operations like scrolling, filtering, etc. Cell elements are much more flexible and overcome the limitations that Controls introduce and also, they are lightweight elements, as opposed to controls, which provides great performance, hence the grid can display plenty of data.

I hope I managed to explain why I don’t think this is a good idea.

The elements - icon and text, that you have hidden, are there precisely to show the user that these are filter cells.

If you need faster input, you can perhaps open the editor automatically (using CurrentCellChanged and BEginEdit method) when the user clicks on it.